# Show that $f'(x) \simeq \frac{1}{12h} [-f(x+2h) + 8f(x+h) -8f(x-h) + f(x-2h)]$?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

How would you show that $f'(x) \simeq \frac{1}{12h} [-f(x+2h) + 8f(x+h) -8f(x-h) + f(x-2h)]$?

Here is what I have tried:

It would make sense to me that Richardson extrapolation should/could be used here because the question came up in a chapter about this topic - although it does not have to be. Anyway, so I thought pretty hard but the closest approximation I could come up with was $f'(x) \simeq \frac{1}{12h} [-2f(x+2h) + 8f(x+h) -8f(x-h) + 2f(x-2h)]$. This was derived as follows:

$$
D(n,0) = \frac{1}{2h} [f(x+h/2^n)-f(x-h/2^n)]\\
D(n,k) = \frac{4^k}{4^k-1} D(n,k-1) \frac{1}{4^k-1} D(n-1,k-1)\\
D(0,1) = \frac{4^1}{4^1 - 1} D(0,0) - \frac{1}{4^1-1} D(-1, 0)\\
\Rightarrow D(0,1) = \frac{4}{3} \frac{1}{2h} [f(x+h)-f(x-h)] - \frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{2h} [f(x+2h)-f(x-2h)]\\
= \frac{4}{6h} [f(x+h)-f(x-h)] - \frac{1}{6h} [f(x+2h)-f(x-2h)]\\
= \frac{1}{12h} [-2f(x+2h) + 8f(x+h)-8f(x-h) + 2f(x-2h)]
$$

I was about to get happy but realized that even though it was close, it was not the requested result.

How can I derive $f'(x) \simeq \frac{1}{12h} [-f(x+2h) + 8f(x+h) -8f(x-h) + f(x-2h)]$?

Comment: This depends on what you mean by $\simeq$.  For a very weak version, just take limits as $h$ approaches $0$.

Comment: @Aaron The error should be $O(h^4)$

Comment: Do you know Taylor-Young's formula?

Answer (score 1):

If you know
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h} \to f'(x)$$
$$\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x-2h)}{4h} \to f'(x)$$
then
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{12h}[-f(x+2h) + 8f(x+h) - 8f(x-h) + f(x-2h)]
\\
&= -\frac{1}{3} \frac{f(x+2h)-f(x-2h)}{4h}
+ \frac{4}{3} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h}
\\
&\to f'(x)
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

It results from a short computation with Taylor-Young's formula:  $\;f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+o(h).$
Therefore, using the basic rules of asymptotic calculus,
\begin{align}
&-f(x+2h) + 8f(x+h) -8f(x-h) + f(x-2h)=\\
={}&-f(x)-f'(x)\bigl(2h\bigr)+8f(x)+8f'(x)h -8f(x)-8f'(x)\bigl(-h\bigr)+f(x)+f'(x)\bigl(-2h\bigr)+o(h)\\={}&(-1+8-8+1)f(x)+(-2+8+8-2)f'(x)h+o(h) = 12f'(x)h+o(h)
\end{align}
and ultimately
$$\frac{1}{12h} [-f(x+2h) + 8f(x+h) -8f(x-h) + f(x-2h)]=\frac{12f'(x)h+o(1)}{12h}=f'(x)+o(1).$$

Answer (score 0):

By Taylor's theorem, if $f$ is nice, then for fixed $x$, we can write
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+f''(x)h^2/2 +h'''(x)h^3/6 +f^{(4)}(x)h^4/4!+o(h^4).$$ This yields that $$(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2h)=f'(x)+f'''(x)h^2/6+O(h^4).$$

For ease of notation, let us write $g(h)=(f(x+h)-f(x-h))/(2h)$. For any choice of $a_i,b_i$ such that $\sum a_i=1$, we have that $\sum a_i g(b_ih)=f'(x)+h^2f'''(x)/6\sum a_i b_i^2+O(h^4)$, and the question is whether we can find choices that cause the second term to cancel.

A natural choice of $b_i$ is $b_1=1, b_2=2$, in which case we get the system of equations $a_1+a_2=1, a_1+4a_2=0$, which has solution $a_1=4/3$, $a_2=-1/3$.  Rearranging yields your approximation.

---

For another approach that invokes [Richardson extrapolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson_extrapolation), we start with $g(h)=f'(x)+O(h^2)$.  Then, using the formula from the Wikipedia page with $t=1/2$, we get that $((1/4)g(2h)-g(h))/(1/4-1)=(4g(h)-g(2h))/3=f'(x)+O(h^3)$.  However, because $g(h)$ is an even function, if it is $O(h^3)$ then it is $O(h^4)$.  Simplifying the expression, we get
$$(4g(h)-g(2h))/3=8\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{12h}-\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x-2h)}{12h}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your method is fine and your only mistake is at
$$D(-1,0)=\frac{f(x+2h)-f(x-2h)}{\color{red}{4}h}$$
You didn't correctly assess the distance between the data points!

Answer (score 0):

This is a 4 point derivative approximation. WLOG assume $x = 0$. Then the approximation takes the form
$$D_h(f) = \frac{w_1f(-2h) + w_2f(-h) + w_3f(h) + w_4f(2h)}{h},$$
Where $w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4$ are to be determined. To get the coefficients, set $D_h(f) = 0$ for $f = 1, x, x^2, x^3$ to get the linear system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
-2 & -1 & 1 & 2 \\
4 & 1 & 1 & 4 \\
-8 & -1 & 1 & 8 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
w_1 \\
w_2 \\
w_3 \\
w_4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has unique solution
$$w_1 = \frac{1}{12}, w_2 = -\frac{2}{3}, w_3 = \frac{2}{3}, w_4 = -\frac{1}{12}.$$
Let $E_h(f) = f'(0) - D_h(f)$. Note that $E_h$ is a linear map. By symmetry, $E_h(x^4) = 0$. But $E_h(x^5) = 4h^4$. This implies that the method has error
$$E_h(f) = \frac{f^{(5)}(0)}{5!} \cdot 4h^4 + O(h^5),$$
This can easily be derived as follows. Assume $f$ has $6$ continuous derivatives on $[-2h, 2h]$. Then by Taylor's theorem,
\begin{align} 
E_h(f) &= E_h\left(\sum_{n = 0}^{5}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n + \frac{f^{(6)}(\xi(0, x))}{6!}x^6\right) \\
&= \sum_{n = 0}^{5}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}E_h(x^n) + E_h\left(\frac{f^{(6)}(\xi(0, x))}{6!}x^6\right) \\
&= \frac{f^{(5)}(0)}{5!}E_h(x^5) + O(h^5) \\
&= \frac{f^{(5)}(0)}{30}h^4 + O(h^5).
\end{align}
This procedure can be used for other approximation methods, such as integration.